# Ajax/PHP contact form not able to send mail

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax, forms

The funny thing is it did work for one evening. I contacted my host, and they are saying there's no reason it should not be working. I have also attempted to test it in Firebug, but it seemed to be sending. And I specifically put the email address (hosted in my domain) on my email safe list, so that is not the culprit either.

Would anyone here take a look at it for me? I'd be so grateful.

In the header I have:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var options = {
            target: '#alert'
        };
        $('#contactForm').ajaxForm(options);
    });

    $.fn.clearForm = function () {
        return this.each(function () {
            var type = this.type,
                tag = this.tagName.toLowerCase();
            if (tag == 'form')
                return $(':input', this).clearForm();
            if (type == 'text' || type == 'password' || tag == 'textarea')
                this.value = '';
            else if (type == 'checkbox' || type == 'radio')
                this.checked = false;
            else if (tag == 'select')
                this.selectedIndex = -1;
        });
    };
</script>
```

Here is the actual form:

```
<form id="contactForm" method="post" action="sendmail.php"> 

<fieldset> 

<p>Email Me</p> 
<div id="fieldset_container"> 
<label for="name">Your Name:</label> 
<input type="text" name="name" id="name" /><br /><br /> 

<label for="email">Email:</label> 
<input type="text" name="email" id="email" /><br /><br /> 

<span style="display:none;"> 
<label for="last">Honeypot:</label> 
<input type="text" name="last" value="" id="last" /> 
</span><br /><br /> 

<label for="message">Comments &amp; Inquiries:</label> 
<textarea name="message" id="message" cols="" rows=""></textarea><br/> 
</div> 
<div id="submit_button"> 
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Send It" /> 
</div> 
</fieldset> 

</form> 

<div class="message"><div id="alert"></div></div>
```

Here is the code from my validating page, sendmail.php:

```
<?php

//        Who you want to recieve the emails from the form. (Hint: generally you.)
$sendto = 'my@emailaddress.com';

//        The subject you'll see in your inbox
$subject = 'SH Contact Form';

//        Message for the user when he/she doesn't fill in the form correctly.
$errormessage = 'There seems to have been a problem. May I suggest...';

//        Message for the user when he/she fills in the form correctly.
$thanks = "Thanks for the email!";

//        Message for the bot when it fills in in at all.
$honeypot = "You filled in the honeypot! If you're human, try again!";

//        Various messages displayed when the fields are empty.
$emptyname =  'Entering your name?';
$emptyemail = 'Entering your email address?';
$emptymessage = 'Entering a message?';

//       Various messages displayed when the fields are incorrectly formatted.
$alertname =  'Entering your name using only the standard alphabet?';
$alertemail = 'Entering your email in this format: <i>name@example.com</i>?';
$alertmessage = "Making sure you aren't using any parenthesis or other escaping                    characters in the message? Most URLS are fine though!";


//Setting used variables.
$alert = '';
$pass = 0;

// Sanitizing the data, kind of done via error messages first. Twice is better!  ;-)
function clean_var($variable) {
    $variable = strip_tags(stripslashes(trim(rtrim($variable))));
  return $variable;
}

//The first if for honeypot.
if ( empty($_REQUEST['last']) ) {

 // A bunch of if's for all the fields and the error messages.
if ( empty($_REQUEST['name']) ) {
 $pass = 1;
 $alert .= "<li>" . $emptyname . "</li>";
} elseif ( ereg( "[][{}()*+?.\\^$|]", $_REQUEST['name'] ) ) {
 $pass = 1;
 $alert .= "<li>" . $alertname . "</li>";
}
if ( empty($_REQUEST['email']) ) {
 $pass = 1;
 $alert .= "<li>" . $emptyemail . "</li>";
} elseif ( !eregi("^[_a-z0-9-]+(.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(.[a-z0-9-]+)*(.[a-z]{2,3})$", $_REQUEST['email']) ) {
 $pass = 1;
 $alert .= "<li>" . $alertemail . "</li>";
}
if ( empty($_REQUEST['message']) ) {
 $pass = 1;
 $alert .= "<li>" . $emptymessage . "</li>";
} elseif ( ereg( "[][{}()*+?\\^$|]", $_REQUEST['message'] ) ) {
 $pass = 1;
 $alert .= "<li>" . $alertmessage . "</li>";
}

 //If the user err'd, print the error messages.
 if ( $pass==1 ) {

  //This first line is for ajax/javascript, comment it or delete it if this isn't your cup o' tea.
 echo "<script>$(\".message\").hide(\"slow\").show(\"slow\"); </script>";
 echo "<b>" . $errormessage . "</b>";
 echo "<ul>";
 echo $alert;
 echo "</ul>";

 // If the user didn't err and there is in fact a message, time to email it.
 } elseif (isset($_REQUEST['message'])) {

  //Construct the message.
     $message = "From: " . clean_var($_REQUEST['name']) . "\n";
  $message .= "Email: " . clean_var($_REQUEST['email']) . "\n";
     $message .= "Message: \n" . clean_var($_REQUEST['message']);
     $header = 'From:'. clean_var($_REQUEST['email']);

//Mail the message - for production
  mail($sendto, $subject, $message, $header, "-fstephanie@stephaniehenderson.com");
//This is for javascript, 
  echo "<script>$(\".message\").hide(\"slow\").show(\"slow\").animate({opacity: 1.0}, 4000).hide(\"slow\"); $(':input').clearForm() </script>";
  echo $thanks;
  die();

//Echo the email message - for development
  echo "<br/><br/>" . $message;

 }

//If honeypot is filled, trigger the message that bot likely won't see.
} else {
 echo "<script>$(\".message\").hide(\"slow\").show(\"slow\"); </script>";
 echo $honeypot;
}
?>
```

Comment: Oh geez. I ran out of coding allowance or something (I am new here, quite obviously). Any chance someone here can still skim through that for me?

Comment: This is a programming question and will be move to the correct place. Follow it when it moves. But until then, fixed up the formatting for your last chunk, which was missing the indents of four spaces for the lines. You may also need to read this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2508/account-association-between-websites

Answer (score 1):

If the message is echoing then it's not a problem with your javascript or html. I would suggest making a fresh PHP file with only the 1 line that attempts to send mail:

```
mail('youremailaddress@example.com', 'My Subject', 'This is a message');
```

Hardcode *everything*. If that works, then you know that it's probably not a problem with your host, and you need to examine that line and the variables to are passing to mail()